# Socket Programming on Visual C++: recv() returns error code 10053 and 10014 in my TCP Echo Server-Client

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sockets, visual-c++, tcp

## Can anyone please point out the error in my code?

I already have previous knowledge about socket programming in Linux using C. So, I tried writing a **simple TCP echo server and client program** using **Visual C++** on **Visual Studio 2017** in my **Windows 8.1** machine.

I am **able to send any message to the server** or the **client can send any message to any server** using the send() function. But I cannot receive any message using the recv() method. On the **server the recv() function returns the error code 10053** and the **client returns an error code 10014**. Below are the source codes of the programs.

#### tcpServer.cpp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<string.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, cs;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    unsigned short server_port = 4444;
    char* server_ip = "192.168.2.5";
    int client_addr_len;
    char *message = "Hello World";
    int r;
    /*if (argc < 2) {
    printf("usage: tcpServer.exe <your IP address>");
    exit(1);
    }
    strcpy_s(server_ip, argv[1]);*/

    //Display stuff
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\tTCP ECHO SERVER\n\n");
    printf("Creating TCP echo server on the IP %s\n", server_ip);

    //Initialise WinSock
    printf("Initialising WinSock....\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Initialising failed with error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Successfully initialised.\n");

    //Create socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Socket creating failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Socket created successfully.\n");

    //Setting the struct sockaddr_in server_addr
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    //Binding
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Could not bind to port with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Bound to port %d\n", server_port);

    //Start listening for client
    printf("\nListening for client connections on %s:%d\n", server_ip, server_port);
    if (listen(s, 5) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot listen for client connections with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    //Accepting connections
    client_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    if ((cs = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot accept connections with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connection accepted from %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));

    //No need of SOCKET s
    closesocket(s);

    //Receive messages
    if ((r = recv(cs, message, 2000, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot receive messages with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    message = "Hello World";
    printf("Message received: %s\n", message);

    //Send back the message
    send(cs, message, strlen(message), 0);
    printf("Message echoed back to server: %s\n", message);

    //Close and clearing
    closesocket(cs);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

#### tcpClient.cpp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<string.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s, cs;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    unsigned short server_port = 4444;
    char* server_ip = "192.168.2.5";
    int client_addr_len;
    char *message = "Hello World";
    int r;

    system("cls");
    printf("\t\tTCP ECHO CLIENT\n\n");
    printf("Connecting to TCP echo server on the IP %s\n", server_ip);

    printf("Initialising WinSock....\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Initialising failed with error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Successfully initialised.\n");

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Socket creating failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Socket created successfully.\n");

    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot connect to server %s", server_ip);
        closesocket(s);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connected to server %s on port %d\n", server_ip, server_port);

    if (send(s, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Message sending failed with error code %d", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Message sending was successful\n");

    if (recv(s, message, 2000, 0) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Message recieving failed with error code %d", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Message echoed back from server: %s\n", message);
    getchar();

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

### Outputs

[image: Output for tcpServer.cpp]

[image: Output fro tcpClient.cpp]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On both sides, `message` is just a pointer, and you have it pointing at a read-only string literal.  `recv()` is trying to read data into that literal's memory, which will fail.  You need to change `message` to a fixed-sized array instead:

```
//char *message = "Hello World";
char message[2000];
```

On the server side, you are making a similar mistake with your `server_ip` value (if you uncomment the call to `strcpy_n()`).

Also, when calling `recv()`, you are ignoring its return value.  You only check it for -1 (read error), but it can also return 0 (graceful disconnect) or > 0 (data received).  The data is not null-terminated!  You must take the actual number of bytes read into account when calling `printf()` afterwards.  Don't use `strlen()`, unless you null-terminate the data manually.

Try something more like this instead:

Server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s = INVALID_SOCKET, cs = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    unsigned short server_port = 4444;
    char* server_ip;
    int client_addr_len;
    char message[2000];
    int r, exitCode = 1;

    /*if (argc < 2) {
        printf("usage: tcpServer.exe <your IP address>");
        exit(1);
    }
    server_ip = argv[1];
    */
    server_ip = "192.168.2.5";

    //Display stuff
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\tTCP ECHO SERVER\n\n");
    printf("Creating TCP echo server on the IP %s\n", server_ip);

    //Initialise WinSock
    printf("Initialising WinSock....\n");
    if ((r = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa)) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Initialising failed with error Code : %d", r);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Successfully initialised.\n");

    //Create socket
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("ERROR: Socket creating failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }
    printf("Socket created successfully.\n");

    //Setting the struct sockaddr_in server_addr
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    //Binding
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("ERROR: Could not bind to port with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }
    printf("Bound to port %d\n", server_port);

    //Start listening for client
    printf("\nListening for client connection on %s:%d\n", server_ip, server_port);
    if (listen(s, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot listen for client connection with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    //Accepting connection
    client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    if ((cs = accept(s, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot accept connection with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("Connection accepted from %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));

    //No need of SOCKET s anymore
    closesocket(s);
    s = INVALID_SOCKET;

    //Receive messages
    if ((r = recv(cs, message, 2000, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot receive message with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if (r == 0) {
        printf("Client disconnected");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("Message received: %.*s\n", r, message);

    //Send back the message
    if (send(cs, message, r, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot send message with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("Message echoed back to client: %.*s\n", r, message);

    exitCode = 0;

cleanup:

    //Close and clearing
    if (cs != INVALID_SOCKET) closesocket(cs);
    if (s != INVALID_SOCKET) closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return exitCode;
}
```

Client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    unsigned short server_port = 4444;
    char* server_ip = "192.168.2.5";
    int client_addr_len;
    char message[2000];
    int r, exitCode = 1;

    system("cls");
    printf("\t\tTCP ECHO CLIENT\n\n");
    printf("Connecting to TCP echo server on the IP %s\n", server_ip);

    printf("Initialising WinSock....\n");
    if ((r = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa)) != 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Initialising failed with error Code : %d", r);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Successfully initialised.\n");

    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("ERROR: Socket creating failed with error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }
    printf("Socket created successfully.\n");

    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(server_port);

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot connect to server %s", server_ip);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    printf("Connected to server %s on port %d\n", server_ip, server_port);

    strcpy_s(message, sizeof(message), "Hello World");
    if (send(s, message, strlen(message), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("ERROR: Message sending failed with error code %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }
    printf("Message sending was successful\n");

    if ((r = recv(s, message, sizeof(message), 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("ERROR: Message receiving failed with error code %d", WSAGetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if (r == 0) {
        printf("Server disconnected");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    printf("Message echoed back from server: %.*s\n", r, message);
    getchar();

    exitCode = 0;

cleanup:

    if (s != INVALID_SOCKET) closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return exitCode;
}
```

That being said, on the server side, when calling `listen()`, there is no point in setting the backlog to 5 if you are only ever going to accept 1 client.  If you really want to implement a useful server, you should be calling `accept()` in a loop instead for the lifetime of the server, using `select()` or worker threads to monitor connected clients.

Comment: Thanks for the info Remy Lebeau. Will try it right away.